# ISODATA unsupervised classification in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: classification

I’m doing a project on landsat 5 images. 
I’ve composited the images into 1 raster, and I want to classify the raster with ISODATA Unsupervised Classification. 
How do I calculate the best number of classes in each group, the sample interval and the best minimum class size?
thanks!

Comment: Hi Yael.  Are you trying to create a land cover classification or some other output?

Comment: Hi. I want to create a land cover classification. I'm trying to understand how to choose those values because I need to explain why I worked that way...